# Function to delete image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I understand that I can delete an image using a specific id, but my images do not have an id and I don't know how I would go about this. Basically I want an image to disappear when I click on my button that creates a new image instead of adding it to the page. Here's my code...

http://jsfiddle.net/XF49m/

or

```
function add_conner_6th() {
    var src =
        "src";
    show_image("src", 300,415, "Conner 6th");
```

I basically want to create a new function that deletes the created picture.

Comment: If there are multiple images, how should it determine which one to delete?

Comment: Why don't you give it an ID?

Comment: What is the `src` variable for? You're not using it when you call `show_image()`, you're passing a quoted string.

Comment: You can use `removeChild` or `display: none`

Comment: @inf3rno You still need to find the element to remove or set the style of.

Comment: @inf3rno: Yes, but he need to know on which node ...

Comment: @user13500 He can easily add a catalog of url - img element.

Comment: @Barmar How would I give it an ID?! I'm obviously not using HTML and I'm not sure how to using js

Comment: @Barmar Thanks that's all I need to know

Comment: And the id has to be unique to be valid.

Comment: @inf3rno: Yes, but his question was not *how* to remove it, but how to remove the one he wanted.

Comment: Yes @inf3rno but now I cannot get the removeChild to work... haha

Comment: `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)`, you can find the `img` by id, or you can create an url - img catalog

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = {
    catalog: {},
    add: function (src, width, height, alt){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        this.catalog[src] = img;
    },
    remove: function (src){
        var img = this.catalog[src];
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
        delete(this.catalog[src]);
    }
};

function add_conner_6th() {
    var src = "src";
    images.add("src", 300,415, "Conner 6th");
}

function remove_conner_6th(){
    var src = "src";
    images.remove("src");
}
```